# See android app logs without running from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I'm trying to fix a bug that happens when the application is installed and the user adds the `app widget` before running the app for the first time.

The question is if there is a way to intall app and see the logs from `Android Studio` without running it.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't comment on Android Studio, but `adb logcat` might get you what you want.

Comment: Change your Android Studio run configuration to not launch an activity. While the default is for Android Studio to launch your launcher activity, you can override that to have it simply install the app and launch nothing.

Comment: That's it, thank you!